# android - how to call a method from another activity, from a reciever class?

Tags: android, methods, broadcast

I am using a reciever class defined in the manifest like

```
    <receiver 
      android:name="com.escortme.basic.SMSReceiverActivity"
      android:enabled="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

to listen on incoming texts, but the problem is how do I call a method which is the current activity that the phone is showing, from the onrecieve method in SMSReceiverActivity ?

So for example, if I am currently on pol_viewactivity on my phone, then i recieve a text, i know that the onrecieve method occured in the background from SMSReceiverActivity, but in the onreceive method, how do I call a method back from pol_viewactivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should either

1) put your `onReceive` method in your `pol_viewactivity`; or,

2) provide a listener in `SMSReceiverActivity` and set by `pol_viewactivity`.

**EDITED:**

In response to how to create a listener.

In your `SMSReceiverActivity`, define an interface,

```
public interface ExampleListener {
    onMsgReceive(String msg);
}
```

declare the listener and a public method,

```
private ExampleListener listener;

public void setExampleListener(ExampleListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

In the `onReceive` method of the `BroadcastReceiver`,

```
if (listener != null) {
    listener.onMsgReceive("Your message to pass");
}
```

In your `pol_viewactivity`, find ways to set the listener similar to the way of calling `setOnClickListener()`. If you cannot retrieve the instance of the `SMSReceiverActivity` in order to set the listener, then make the listener static. I know this is not a beautiful way to do so, but in your case, if you can't change the design, this way should help. (Perhaps you can isolate the BroadcastReceiver into a single class and do all the handling there.)

Comment: for number 1) both pol_viewactivity and the SMSReceiverActivity extends other classes, so i dont understand how to do this
for number 2) can you please show me how I can do this in code?